# Cordova CLI Android/gradle in Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, cordova, gradle

While trying to publish my cordova app for android after an Android SDK update I am getting the error below.

I have set my environment variables as per below and I have the latest java sdk.
I have tried downloading the latest gradle and set the environment variables to point to the extracted files and I tried the zipped files, and I have pointed it to an online service. Neither made a change.

Can someone explain the errors and point me in the right direction

> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Johnathan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
>   (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Johnathan\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
>   (DEPRECATED) Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)
>   C:\usb_webserver\root\cordova\Sunpharma\slate\platforms\android\gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:62)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my gradle was still referencing the old installation.  I had to manually remove the old installation before the computer would recognise the newer version even though the newer installation was fine.